# Tkinter Treeview identify on right click event returns previous right clicked row

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, event-handling, treeview

I have a treeview in tkinter using python 3.
The problem is that when I bind a right-click to get the row ID of the right-clicked row, I end up getting the actual row ID of the previous event. For example, I might right-click "Project 1", this will return me "" and then I right-click "Project 2" and it returns "Project 1" as rowID.

```
def initTreeView(self):
    self.treeView = ttk.Treeview(self.treeSectionFrame)
    self.treeView.heading('#0', text='Projects')

    self.treeView.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=("N", "S", "E", "W"))            


    self.treeView.bind('<3>', self.rightClickMenu)

def rightClickMenu(self, event):
    def hello():
        print("hello!")
    # create a popup menu
    print(event.x, event.y)
    rowID = self.treeView.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
    if rowID:
        menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Undo", command=hello)
        menu.add_command(label="Redo", command=hello)
        menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

        self.treeView.selection_set(rowID)
        self.treeView.focus_set()
        self.treeView.focus(rowID)
        print(rowID)
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks,

[EDIT]

I've found a dirty hack which consists of making the tags of each item the same as its id so you can then fetch the actual rowID. This can also be done using the value option.

```
self.treeView.insert("", "end", "id-1, tags="id-1", text="Project 1")

...
rowID = self.treeView.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
rowID = self.treeView.item(rowID)["tags"] # gives you actual ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to print the actual `rowID`, then just print it right away:

```
...
rowID = self.treeView.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
print(rowID)
...
```

... but of course, this is not what you're expecting from the code. To overcome this problem — let's invert logic a little bit:

```
def rightClickMenu(self, event):
    def hello():
        print("hello!")
    # create a popup menu
    print(event.x, event.y)
    rowID = self.treeView.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
    if rowID:
        self.treeView.selection_set(rowID)
        self.treeView.focus_set()
        self.treeView.focus(rowID)
        print(rowID)

        menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Undo", command=hello)
        menu.add_command(label="Redo", command=hello)
        menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    else:
        pass
```

As you can see, now changing selections aren't blocked by the `Menu` widget.

The reason why it's works like that is because [`post`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/menu.htm#M66) method displays `Menu` right away and this event needs to be handled by `tk` somehow. Thus, we have the main problem: the positioning of that `post`.

Another approach example:

```
    ...
    menu = Menu(self.root, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_command(label="Undo", command=hello)
    menu.add_command(label="Redo", command=hello)

    self.treeView.selection_set(rowID)
    self.treeView.focus_set()
    self.treeView.focus(rowID)
    print(rowID)
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    ...
```

But in my opinion, I think that the most logically correct option here is to extract selection handling to another function, and use it as a `postcommand` argument of `Menu`. So that after that you aren't trying to sit on two chairs at the same time with one callback function.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly now. How does inverting it make it work?

Comment: @I am Legend, because there's some sort of overlapping in events queue(I assume that), it's looks like `tkinter` returns to mainloop, because user can interact with menu, and code execution blocked while menu is visible. Anyway I slighty updated my answer.